# How to copy all data from DataGrid and paste into DataTable? (C # / WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

DataGrid using DataTable gets dynamic data to display. All changes made to the data occur in the DataGrid (change the name of the columns, delete columns, change the order of the columns, etc.). To upload converted data, you need to use DataTable ...

Since all changes occurred in the DataGrid, they did not change in the DataTable. How to copy all changed data from DataGrid and paste into DataTable?

```
// For example: Changing column names
DataGridColumn columnHeader = CsvGrid.CurrentColumn;
if (columnHeader != null)
{
    string input = new InputBox(columnHeader.Header.ToString()).ShowDialog();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        _csvTable.Columns[columnHeader.Header.ToString()].ColumnName = input;
        columnHeader.Header = input;
        GetChecksBox();
     }
}
```

I need something like this:

> DataTable ... = DataGrid.ItemsSource;

Comment: You should look into MVVM style of coding. You are putting yourself at a disadvantage with the style of code you are creating and the problems you have posted the last couple of days could have easily been avoided with proper binding.  There are many tutorials on the web available.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DataTable DataGridtoDataTable(DataGrid dg)
    {


        dg.SelectAllCells();
        dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);
        dg.UnselectAllCells();
        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        string[] Lines = result.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] Fields;
        Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
        int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToUpper(), typeof(string));
        DataRow Row;
        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0)-1; i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
            {
                Row[f] = Fields[f];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(Row);
        }
        return dt;

    }
```

Check this

Answer (score 1):

Does it solve the problem?

```
DataTable dt = DataGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol 'DataSource'` And if you use 'ItemsSource' then I get the following `Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' and 'System.Data.DataTable'`